# Is it possible to pipe multiple audio sources into a single virtual “microphone” input?

Tags: windows, audio

**Problem:** I want to be able to pipe audio from some application into my microphone, so I can overlay sound effects into games. This is not for the intention of “mic spamming,” but a similar concept applies.

I want to play youtube videos, audio files from Winamp, or whatever, into my “Mic” device. Obviously this will be a virtual microphone, and not a real microphone, since I don’t want all the delay/interference of playing audio into a physical speaker and sending it back thru a physical microphone. The sound quality is horrible, inaudible and is very annoying.

**One more aspect of the problem:** I don’t want to replace my entire microphone line with just YouTube. I want to be able to speak and have YouTube playing into a game/Skype chat/stream/etc. Something that allows piping multiple audio sources into a single line, simultaneously.

Comment: How do you mean, sending it to a mic? Or do you simply want to record what you're hearing, is that it?

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/q/472045/52492,  http://superuser.com/q/274120/52492

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to record the audio of something you are watching online, you can do that with the **Stereo Mix** option in Windows.  It's available in Windows 7 for any device, but it should be available on most audio devices in Vista and XP.

To enable it in Windows 7, right click on the speaker icon in your task bar and select **Recording Devices**.  You will be presented with the following screen:

[image: Stereo Mix]

If the Stereo Mix option is not showing, you may have to enable it by right-clicking the box of devices and select **Show disabled devices**.  Once it's visible, right click Stereo Mix and select **Set as default device** and you're done.  When you use any program to record, it should now pick up any sounds that are being played through your sound card at the moment.  Just be aware that this means it will pick up other system noises as well (like email or IM notifications, system errors, etc.).

Comment: I enabled Stereo Mix, but no sound shows up (no bar either).

Comment: First off, make sure it's set to `Default Device`, not the `Default Communication Device`.  You may want to look at the links RedGrittyBrick posted in comments on your question.  There are more troubleshooting options listed there.  What program are you using to record?  There may be additional settings in it that are necessary to use the Stereo Mix.

Comment: Trying to play audio into skype basically (not prank calls).

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do that.  If you're talking to someone and you have it set to put the Stereo Mix straight into Skype, you wouldn't be able to speak through your mic (I imagine it would be set to allow only one input device at a time), and anything they said would just be played back to them through the Stereo Mix.

Comment: I couldn't find "Stereo Mix" (even disabled/disconnected), but found [a thread](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f23/solved-realtek-hd-audio-stereo-mix-record-460599.html) where users reported downgrading their RealTek driver to make it reappear. Search Google for version 6.0.1.5322. If Windows keeps saying you have the latest driver, see [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/637817/how-can-i-forcibly-install-an-older-driver-on-windows-7). In "Have disk...", select the "HDX.inf" file, which for me was in the "Vista64" directory of the driver package I downloaded from CNET.

Comment: @techturtle: "Trying to play audio into skype basically (not prank calls)." -> "I'm not sure you want to do that." - I'm not sure what's the point of "questioning the premise" here. If the OP's intention is to mix (real) microphone input + audio output of one or more other applications, and the offered solution does not allow for that, then maybe this solution is simply not the right solution for this particular problem?